# LaTeX Compile Error due to CJK error

Tags: cjk

I am writing my PhD thesis in WinEdt 10.2 with MikTeX support. My thesis needs to include cover page having chinese fonts. University thesis class has all the definitions. When I compile the main text file, it gives error:

> *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
>
> *geometry* detected driver: pdftex
>
> (Main.out) (Main.out)
>
> ! Package CJK Error: Invalid character code.
>
> See the CJK package documentation for explanation.
> Type H  for immediate help.
> ...
> l.114 \makeCoverPage
> ?
>
> Process has been terminated ...

I have included necessary CJK package in the tex file.
Previously, it was running fine. Last week, I tried to install TeX Live which took too much time to install. After that this problem occured. I have removed TeX Live 2023 but the problem still persists. May be, Tex Live has removed some necessary files from my computer.

If i don't include CJK package in main tex file then following error occurs:

> Missing character: There is no · in font ptmr7t!
>
> ! Package CJK Error: Invalid character code.

Main.tex file is:

```
\expandafter\def\csname CTEX@spaceChar\endcsname{\hspace{1em}}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@subfig.sty\endcsname{}
\documentclass[oneside]{ZJUthesis}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm,amsmath,mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{epstopdf,epsfig}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}
%\usepackage{CJK,CJKnumb}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\let\abbrev\nomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature
\newcommand{\Abkuerzung}{
\printnomenclature
\newpage
}

\newcommand{\zht}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}#1\end{CJK}}
\newcommand{\zhs}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}#1\end{CJK}}
\newcommand{\zh}[4]{\zht{#1}/\zhs{#2} (\emph{#3}) ``#4''}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{algorithm}{chapter}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}

\begin{document}

\fangsong
%\zihao{-4}

\classification{}

\serialnumber{}

\PersonalID{}

\Etitle{}
\Etitletl}

\author{}

\degree{}

\submitdate{2023.7}

\defenddate{2023.9}

\makeCoverPage

\reviewersA{}
\reviewersB{}
\reviewersC{}
\reviewersD{}
\reviewersE{}

\chairman{}
\commissionerA{}
\commissionerB{}
\commissionerC{}
\commissionerD{}

\maketitle

\englishtitle{}

\englishtitletl{}


\EreviewersA{Anonymous}
\EreviewersB{Anonymous}
\EreviewersC{Anonymous}
\EreviewersD{Anonymous}
\EreviewersE{Anonymous}

\Echairman{}
\EcommissionerA{}
\EcommissionerB{}
\EcommissionerC{}
\EcommissionerD{}


\makeenglishtitle

\SignautreDateA{}{}{}
\SignautreDateB{}{}{}
\SignautreDateC{}{}{}

\makeOSandCPRTpage

\ZJUfrontmatter

\input{./Chapters/Thanks}

\input{./Chapters/AbstractC}

\input{./Chapters/AbstractE}

\ZJUListofFigures

\ZJUListofTables

\input{./Chapters/Abbreviations}

\ZJUcontents

\ZJUmainmatter

\input{./Chapters/Chapter1}

\ZJUbackmatter

\appendix
\input{./Chapters/Appendix}

\ZJUindex

\input{./Chapters/PublicationList}

\end{document}

%*******************************
```

ZJUthesis.cls is also attached for your reference.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{ZJUthesis}[2013/01/25 v2.0 ZJUthesis document class]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{ctexart}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[cs4size,a4paper,fancyhdr,hyperref]{ctexbook}[2009/09/13]
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{times}
%\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage[titles, subfigure]{tocloft}
\RequirePackage[chapter]{tocbibind}
\RequirePackage{makeidx}
\RequirePackage[sort&compress,longnamesfirst,square,numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[margin=10pt,font={small,bf},labelsep=quad]{caption}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{CJKbookmarks=true,%
       bookmarksnumbered,%
               linkcolor=blue,%
              plainpages=false,%
            pdfstartview=FitH,
               hidelinks
         }
\AtBeginDocument{\makeatletter\input{ZJUthesis.cfg}\makeatother}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,%
top=51pt,bottom=51pt,left=68pt,right=57pt,%
headsep=14pt,footskip=26pt,%
footnotesep=10.8pt plus 1fil minus 2.0pt,%
includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{subfigure}
\RequirePackage{upgreek}
\RequirePackage{enumerate}

%\oddsidemargin -0.14 true cm
% ż��ҳ�����߾���������˫��ģʽ�뵥��ģʽ��������
%\if@twoside
%  \evensidemargin -0.34 true cm
%\else
%  \evensidemargin -0.14 true cm
%\fi
% ����ҳͷ�հ׳ߴ�
%\topmargin -0.74 true cm
%\headheight 0.8 true cm
%\headsep 0.5 true cm
\topsep 0.7 true cm
%\textheight 23.9 true cm
%\textwidth 16.6 true cm
%\footskip 0.9 true cm
\parskip 0.5ex plus 0.25ex minus 0.25ex
% cleardoublepage���������Ķ���
\def\cleardoublepage{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd
      \c@page
    \else
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \hbox{}\newpage
      \if@twocolumn
        \hbox{}\newpage
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.15}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.65}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.60}

%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{figure}}

\newcommand\ZJUspace{\protect\CTEX@spaceChar\protect\CTEX@spaceChar}
\def\reserved@a#1 #2 #3\@nil{%
  \def\ZJUfiledate{#1}%
  \def\ZJUfileversion{#2}%
  \def\ZJUfileinfo{#3}}%
\edef\reserved@b{\csname ver@ZJUthesis.cls\endcsname}
\expandafter\reserved@a\reserved@b\@nil\relax

% ������Nchapter�Ķ���
% ������mainmatter��Ӧ��tex�ĵ��еĶ���
\newcommand\Nchapter[1]{%
  \if@mainmatter%
    \@mainmatterfalse%
    \chapter{#1}%
    \@mainmattertrue%
  \else
    \chapter{#1}%
  \fi}

\def\ZJU@underline[#1]#2{%
  \underline{\hbox to #1{\hfil#2\hfil}}}
\def\ZJUunderline{\@ifnextchar[\ZJU@underline\underline}
\newcommand\classification[1]{\def\ZJU@value@classification{#1}}
\newcommand\confidential[1]{\def\ZJU@value@confidential{#1}}
\newcommand\UDC[1]{\def\ZJU@value@UDC{#1}}
\newcommand\serialnumber[1]{\def\ZJU@value@serialnumber{#1}}
\newcommand\school[1]{\def\ZJU@value@school{#1}}
\newcommand\SecretLevel[1]{%
  \def\ZJU@value@SecretLevel{#1}
  \def\ZJU@value@IsSecret{1}}
\newcommand\PersonalID[1]{\def\ZJU@value@PersonalID{#1}}
\newcommand\degree[1]{\def\ZJU@value@degree{#1}}
\renewcommand\title[2][\ZJU@value@title]{%
  \def\ZJU@value@title{#2}
  \def\ZJU@value@titlemark{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\newcommand\titletl[1]{\def\ZJU@value@titletl{#1}}
\newcommand\Etitle[1]{\def\ZJU@value@Etitle{#1}}
\newcommand\Etitletl[1]{\def\ZJU@value@Etitletl{#1}}
\newcommand\EtitletB[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EtitletB{#1}}
\renewcommand\author[1]{\def\ZJU@value@author{#1}}
\newcommand\supervisor[1]{\def\ZJU@value@supervisor{#1}}
\newcommand\cpsupervisor[1]{\def\ZJU@value@cpsupervisor{#1}}
\newcommand\supervisorinstitute[1]{\def\ZJU@value@supervisorinstitute{#1}}
\newcommand\major[1]{\def\ZJU@value@major{#1}}
\newcommand\researchdm[1]{\def\ZJU@value@researchdm{#1}}
\newcommand\submitdate[1]{\def\ZJU@value@submitdate{#1}}
\newcommand\defenddate[1]{\def\ZJU@value@defenddate{#1}}
\newcommand\defenddateE[1]{\def\ZJU@value@defenddateE{#1}}
\newcommand\institute[1]{\def\ZJU@value@institute{#1}}
\newcommand\chairman[1]{\def\ZJU@value@chairman{#1}}
\newcommand\commissionerA[1]{\def\ZJU@value@commissionerA{#1}}
\newcommand\commissionerB[1]{\def\ZJU@value@commissionerB{#1}}
\newcommand\commissionerC[1]{\def\ZJU@value@commissionerC{#1}}
\newcommand\commissionerD[1]{\def\ZJU@value@commissionerD{#1}}
%\newcommand\commissionerE[1]{\def\ZJU@value@commissionerE{#1}}
\newcommand\reviewersA[1]{\def\ZJU@value@reviewersA{#1}}
\newcommand\reviewersB[1]{\def\ZJU@value@reviewersB{#1}}
\newcommand\reviewersC[1]{\def\ZJU@value@reviewersC{#1}}
\newcommand\reviewersD[1]{\def\ZJU@value@reviewersD{#1}}
\newcommand\reviewersE[1]{\def\ZJU@value@reviewersE{#1}}

\newcommand\SignautreDateA[3]{%
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateAy{#1}
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateAm{#2}
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateAd{#3}}
\newcommand\SignautreDateB[3]{%
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateBy{#1}
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateBm{#2}
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateBd{#3}}
\newcommand\SignautreDateC[3]{%
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateCy{#1}
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateCm{#2}
\def\ZJU@value@signaturedateCd{#3}}
\newcommand\PutsigndateA{%
ǩ�����ڣ�{\includegraphics[width=40pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/2022.pdf}}��
  {\includegraphics[width=20pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/6.pdf}}��
  {\includegraphics[width=20pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/7.pdf}}��
}
\newcommand\PutsigndateB{%
ǩ�����ڣ�{\includegraphics[width=40pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/2022.pdf}}��
  {\includegraphics[width=20pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/6.pdf}}��
  {\includegraphics[width=20pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/7.pdf}}��
}
\newcommand\PutsigndateC{%
ǩ�����ڣ�{\includegraphics[width=40pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/2022.pdf}}��
  {\includegraphics[width=20pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/6.pdf}}��
  {\includegraphics[width=20pt,height=20pt]{./Signature/7.pdf}}��
}
% ��������������
\newcommand\makeCoverPage{%
  % �����ط�д���Ƿ����ϵķ�������ѧ�ţ������ֺſ��Ը���
  \pagenumbering{alph}
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  {
    \songti\zihao{-4}
    \linespread{1.3}
    \begin{center}
      {\hspace{2em}
      \ZJU@label@classification~
      \ZJUunderline[90pt]{\ZJU@value@classification}
      \hfill
      \ZJU@label@serialnumber~
      \ZJUunderline[60pt]{\ZJU@value@serialnumber} \\
      \vspace{3pt}
      \ifx\ZJU@value@IsSecret\undefined
      \else
        \hspace{2em}
        \ZJU@label@SecretLevel~
        \ZJUunderline[90pt]{\ZJU@value@SecretLevel}
      \fi
      \hfill
      \ZJU@label@PersonalID~
      \ZJUunderline[60pt]{\ZJU@value@PersonalID}\\
      }
      % �����ߴ����Ը���
      \vspace{10mm}
      % �㽭��ѧ�ĸ���
      \ifpdf
        \includegraphics[width=60.3mm]{./CoverPagepic/ZJDX.pdf} \\
      \else
        \includegraphics[width=60.3mm]{./CoverPagepic/ZJDX.eps} \\
      \fi
      % �����ߴ����Ը���
      \vspace{4mm}
      %% \ZJU@value@school \\  \zihao{-1}
      % ������ʿѧλ������def�ļ������У���Ȼ��tex�ļ��л����Ը���
      \centerline{\songti \zihao{-1}{\ZJU@value@degree\ZJU@label@thesis} }
      % �����ߴ����Ը���
      \vspace{4mm}
      % �����ط����������ձ�
      \ifpdf
        \includegraphics[width=22.8mm]{./CoverPagepic/QSY.pdf}    \\
      \else
        \includegraphics[width=22.8mm]{./CoverPagepic/QSY.eps}    \\
      \fi
    \end{center}

      \vspace{2mm}

    \begin{center}
      % ������Ŀ�������ݣ������޸�
      \begin{tabular}{rl}
        {\bfseries\fangsong\zihao{3}\ZJU@label@title:}
        &
        \bfseries\fangsong\zihao{-2} \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@title} \\[3mm]
        &
        % �����ط������ڶ��б������жϣ���������һ��д���£��еڶ�������ʾ����������ʾ
        \ifx\ZJU@value@titletl\undefined
          \hfil
        \else
          {\bfseries\fangsong\zihao{-2}\ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@titletl}}
        \fi \\[4mm]
        {\bfseries\fangsong\zihao{3}\ZJU@label@Etitle:}
        &
        {\bf\zihao{-3}\ZJUunderline[300pt]{\ZJU@value@Etitle}}\\[3mm]
        &
        %ͬ����Ӣ�ı����Ķ����жϣ�����һ��д���£��еڶ�����ʾ����������ʾ�ڶ���
        \ifx\ZJU@value@Etitletl\undefined
          \hfil
        \else
          {\bf\zihao{-3}\ZJUunderline[300pt]{\ZJU@value@Etitletl}}
        \fi\\[2mm]
        &
        \ifx\ZJU@value@EtitletB\undefined
          \hfil
        \else
          {\bf\zihao{-3}\ZJUunderline[300pt]{\ZJU@value@EtitletB}}
        \fi\\
      \end{tabular}

      % �������������޸�
      \vspace{6mm}

      % �����������岻ͬ������������AB�����룬���������õ���array����
      \newcolumntype{A}{>{\songti}r<{}}
      \newcolumntype{B}{>{\fangsong}l<{}}
      \zihao{4}
      \begin{tabular}{A@{��}B}
        \ZJU@label@author & \ZJUunderline[200pt]{\ZJU@value@author} \\[3mm]
        \ZJU@label@supervisor & \ZJUunderline[200pt]{\ZJU@value@supervisor} \\[3mm]
        % �ж���û�к�����ʦ
        \ifx\ZJU@value@cpsupervisor\undefined
        \else
         \ZJU@label@cpsupervisor
        \fi
        &
        \ifx\ZJU@value@cpsupervisor\undefined
        \hfil\\[-7.7mm]
        \else
          \ZJUunderline[200pt]{\ZJU@value@cpsupervisor} \\[3mm]
        \fi
        \ZJU@label@major & \ZJUunderline[200pt]{\ZJU@value@major} \\[3mm]
        \ZJU@label@researchdm & \ZJUunderline[200pt]{\ZJU@value@researchdm} \\[3mm]
        \ZJU@label@institute & \ZJUunderline[200pt]{\ZJU@value@institute} \\
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    % �����ʵ��Ŀհ�
    \vfill
    % ����һ�� �����ύ����
    \hfil{\bfseries\songti\zihao{-3}\hspace{4em}\ZJU@label@submitdate%
    \ZJUunderline[150pt]{\ZJU@value@submitdate}}\hfil
  }
}

%������������ҳ
\renewcommand\maketitle{%

  \cleardoublepage

  \thispagestyle{empty}
  {
    \linespread{1.3}
    \begin{center}

      % �Ȳ�������������Ŀ
      {\bfseries\fangsong\zihao{-2}\ZJUunderline[340pt]{\ZJU@value@title}\\
      \ifx\ZJU@value@titletl\undefined
        \hfil\\
      \else
        \ZJUunderline[300pt]{\ZJU@value@titletl}\\
      \fi}

      % ����һ�ξ���
      \vspace{12mm}

      % ���������ձ�
      \ifpdf
        \includegraphics[width=22.8mm]{./CoverPagepic/QSY.pdf}    \\
      \else
        \includegraphics[width=22.8mm]{./CoverPagepic/QSY.eps}    \\
      \fi

      % �����հ�
      \vspace{8mm}
      {\bfseries\songti\zihao{3}
      ��������ǩ����
      \ifpdf
          \ZJUunderline[120pt]{\includegraphics[width=120pt,height=45pt]{./Signature/sign_ch2.pdf}}
      \else
          \ZJUunderline[120pt]{}
      \fi
      {\bfseries\songti\zihao{3}\textcolor{white}{��}}\\

      % �����հ�
      \vspace{3mm}

      %\hfil\\
      ָ����ʦǩ����}
      \ifpdf
           \ZJUunderline[120pt]{\includegraphics[width=120pt,height=45pt]{./Signature/sign_ch1.pdf}}
      \else
           \ZJUunderline[120pt]{}
      \fi
      {\bfseries\songti\zihao{3}\textcolor{white}{��}}\\


      % �����հ�
      \vspace{15mm}

      % ��������Ϣ
      \newcolumntype{A}{>{\songti\zihao{4}}r}
      \newcolumntype{B}{>{\songti\zihao{4}}c}
      \begin{tabular}{A@{��}B}
        ����������1 & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@reviewersA}\\[2.2mm]
        ������2 & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@reviewersB}\\[2.2mm]
        ������3 & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@reviewersC}\\[2.2mm]
        ������4 & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@reviewersD}\\[2.2mm]
        ������5 & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@reviewersE}\\
      \end{tabular}

      % ��һ�οհ�
      \vspace{10mm}

      % ����ίԱ������
      \begin{tabular}{A@{��}B}
        ����ίԱ����ϯ & \ZJUunderline[320pt]{\ZJU@value@chairman}\\[2.2mm]
        ίԱ1 & \ZJUunderline[320pt]{\ZJU@value@commissionerA}\\[2.2mm]
        ίԱ2 & \ZJUunderline[320pt]{\ZJU@value@commissionerB}\\[2.2mm]
        ίԱ3 & \ZJUunderline[320pt]{\ZJU@value@commissionerC}\\[2.2mm]
        ίԱ4 & \ZJUunderline[320pt]{\ZJU@value@commissionerD}\\[2.2mm]
%        ίԱ5 & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@commissionerE}\\
      \end{tabular}

    \end{center}
    % ��һ�οɱ��հ�
      \vfil
    % ����ʱ��
      {\songti\zihao{4}\hfill\ZJU@label@defenddate%
      \ZJUunderline[150pt]{\ZJU@value@defenddate}\hspace{3em}}
  }
}

% �����ط�������Ӣ�ı���ҳ
\newcommand\englishtitle[1]{\def\ZJU@value@englishtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\englishtitletl[1]{\def\ZJU@value@englishtitletl{#1}}
\newcommand\EreviewersA[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EreviewersA{#1}}
\newcommand\EreviewersB[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EreviewersB{#1}}
\newcommand\EreviewersC[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EreviewersC{#1}}
\newcommand\EreviewersD[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EreviewersD{#1}}
\newcommand\EreviewersE[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EreviewersE{#1}}
\newcommand\Echairman[1]{\def\ZJU@value@Echairman{#1}}
\newcommand\EcommissionerA[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EcommissionerA{#1}}
\newcommand\EcommissionerB[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EcommissionerB{#1}}
\newcommand\EcommissionerC[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EcommissionerC{#1}}
\newcommand\EcommissionerD[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EcommissionerD{#1}}
%\newcommand\EcommissionerE[1]{\def\ZJU@value@EcommissionerE{#1}}

\newcommand\makeenglishtitle{%
% ע������cleardoublepage���÷�
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  {
    \linespread{1.3}
    \begin{center}
      % Ӣ��������Ŀ
      {\bf\zihao{-3}\ZJUunderline[400pt]{\ZJU@value@englishtitle}\\
      \vspace{1ex}
      % �ж�Ӣ�ı������޵ڶ���
      \ifx\ZJU@value@englishtitletl\undefined
        \hfil
      \else
        \ZJUunderline[360pt]{\ZJU@value@englishtitletl}
      \fi}

      % ����һ�οհ׾���
      \vspace{7mm}

      % ����У��
      \ifpdf
        \includegraphics[width=22.8mm]{./CoverPagepic/QSY.pdf}    \\
      \else
        \includegraphics[width=22.8mm]{./CoverPagepic/QSY.eps}    \\
      \fi

      % ����һ�οհ׾���
      \vspace{1mm}

      % ����Ӣ��ǩ��
      {\bf\zihao{3}\hspace{1.7em}Author's signature:
      \ifpdf
      \ZJUunderline[120pt]{\includegraphics[width=120pt,height=45pt]{./Signature/sign_en2.pdf}}\\
      \else
      \ZJUunderline[120pt]{}
      \fi
      %\hfil\\
      % ��ʦӢ��ǩ��
      Supervisor's signature:
      \ifpdf
      \ZJUunderline[120pt]{\includegraphics[width=120pt,height=45pt]{./Signature/sign_en1.pdf}}\\
      \else
      \ZJUunderline[120pt]{}
      \fi}
    \end{center}

    % ����һ�οհ�
    \vspace{7mm}

    \zihao{4}
    % �����������б���Ӣ�ģ�
    %\newcolumntype{A}{>{\zihao{4}}r}
    %\newcolumntype{B}{>{\zihao{4}}c}
    \begin{tabular}{rc}
      External Reviewers: & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EreviewersA}\\[1.2mm]
      & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EreviewersB}\\[1.2mm]
      & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EreviewersC}\\[1.2mm]
      & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EreviewersD}\\[1.2mm]
      & \ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EreviewersE}\\
    \end{tabular}

    % ����һ�οհ�
    \vspace{6mm}

    % ����ίԱ��������Ӣ�ģ�
    ~\\[1.2mm]
    \hbox to 2.4em{}Examining Committee Chairperson:\\[1.2mm]
    \hbox to 11.4em{}\ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@Echairman}\\[1.2mm]
    \hbox to 2.4em{}Examining Committee Members:\\[1.2mm]
    \hbox to 11.4em{}\ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EcommissionerA}\\[1.2mm]
    \hbox to 11.4em{}\ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EcommissionerB}\\[1.2mm]
    \hbox to 11.4em{}\ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EcommissionerC}\\[1.2mm]
    \hbox to 11.4em{}\ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EcommissionerD}\\[1.2mm]
%    \hbox to 11.4em{}\ZJUunderline[260pt]{\ZJU@value@EcommissionerE}\\

    % ��һ�οհ�
    \vfill
    % ��������
      {\hfill Date of oral defence: \ZJUunderline[150pt]{\ZJU@value@defenddateE}\hspace{3em}}
    %{\hfill Date of oral defence:\ZJUunderline[150pt]{\ZJU@value@defenddateE}\hspace{3em}}
  }
}

% ������������ȨЭ��ת��ҳ
\newcommand\makeOSandCPRTpage{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \input{./Chapters/Copyright.tex}
}

\newcommand\ZJUfrontmatter{%
  \frontmatter
  % ��������ǰ�Ĳ���ҳ����ʽΪ��д��������

  \pagenumbering{Roman}
}

\newcommand\ZJUmainmatter{%
  \mainmatter
}

\newcommand\ZJUbackmatter{%
  \backmatter
}

% ��ҳüҳ�ĸ�ʽ����
% ÿһ��chapter��ʼ�ĵ�һҳ��ҳüҳ����ʽΪplain��ʽ
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% ��������ǰҳ����ҳüҳ�Ŷ��壬��fancyhdr���еĶ���
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \if@twoside
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\zihao{-5} ~\thepage~}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\zihao{-5} ~\thepage~}
  \else
    \fancyfoot[C]{\zihao{-5} ~\thepage~}
  \fi
}

% L���� R���� O����ҳ Eż��ҳ
% һ��ҳ��ҳüҳ����ʽ
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{} %fancyhfʵ����fancyhead��fancyfoot�ĺ��壬���Ĳ�����H��Fָ��
  % �ֵ�˫���ж�ҳü������
  \if@twoside
    \fancyhead[CE]{\songti\zihao{-5}\ZJU@value@school\ZJU@value@degree\ZJU@label@thesis}
    \fancyhead[CO]{\songti\zihao{-5}\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\zihao{-5} ~\thepage~}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\zihao{-5} ~\thepage~}
  \else
    \fancyhead[L]{\songti\zihao{-5}\ZJU@value@school\ZJU@value@degree\ZJU@label@thesis}
    \fancyhead[R]{\songti\zihao{-5}\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\zihao{-5} ~\thepage~}
  \fi

% �����½ڱ�����ʽ
\CTEXsetup[name={,}]{chapter}
\CTEXsetup[number={\arabic{chapter}}]{chapter}
\CTEXsetup[format={\noindent}]{chapter}
\CTEXsetup[nameformat={\bfseries\zihao{-3}}]{chapter}
\CTEXsetup[titleformat={\bfseries\fangsong\zihao{-3}}]{chapter}
\CTEXsetup[format={\noindent}]{section}
\CTEXsetup[nameformat={\bfseries\zihao{4}}]{section}
\CTEXsetup[titleformat={\bfseries\fangsong\zihao{4}}]{section}
\CTEXsetup[format={\noindent}]{subsection}
\CTEXsetup[nameformat={\bfseries\zihao{-4}}]{subsection}
\CTEXsetup[titleformat={\bfseries\fangsong\zihao{-4}}]{subsection}
\CTEXsetup[format={\noindent}]{subsubsection}
\CTEXsetup[nameformat={\bfseries\zihao{-4}}]{subsubsection}
\CTEXsetup[titleformat={\bfseries\fangsong\zihao{-4}}]{subsubsection}
% �˴��½ڱ���ǰ���հ׾���������Ĭ�����ã������޸����ο�ctex�ο��ĵ�ctex.pdf

% ���Ĳ������ֵ��о�����
\linespread{1.5}

% ȥ��Ŀ¼�еĿո��ַ�
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\CTEX@spaceChar\relax}

% ���ø��������Ĳ���
\setcounter{topnumber}{4}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{5}

\setlength{\floatsep}{8pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{8pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}


% ������
\newenvironment{corrigenda}
  {\Nchapter{\ZJU@label@corrigenda}}
  {}

% ��л
\renewenvironment{thanks}
  {\Nchapter{\ZJU@label@thanks}}
  {}

% ����
\newenvironment{preface}
  {\Nchapter{\ZJU@label@preface}}
  {}

% ժҪ
\newenvironment{abstract}
  {\Nchapter{\ZJU@label@abstract}}
  {}

%�ؼ���
\newcommand\keywords[1]{%
  \vspace{2ex}\noindent{\heiti \ZJU@label@keywords} #1}

%Ӣ��ժҪ
\newenvironment{englishabstract}
  {\Nchapter{\ZJU@label@englishabstract}}
  {}

%Ӣ�Ĺؼ���
\newcommand\englishkeywords[1]{%
  \vspace{2ex}\noindent{\bf \ZJU@label@englishkeywords} #1}

% ����Ŀ¼�������г�Ŀ�Σ�
\newcommand\ZJUcontents{%
  % �޸�Ŀ¼�ĸ�ʽ
  \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\fangsong\zihao{-4}}
  \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
  \renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
  \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\rm\zihao{-4}}
  \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
  \renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
  \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fangsong\zihao{-4}}
  \renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rm\zihao{-4}}
  \renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
  \renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
  \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fangsong\zihao{-4}}
  \renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\rm\zihao{-4}}
  \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{-2pt}
  \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-2pt}
  \setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-2pt}
  \setlength{\cftsecindent}{2em}
  \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{4em}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \tableofcontents
  \addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
}

% ��ͼĿ¼
\newcommand\ZJUListofFigures{%
  \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\fangsong\zihao{-4}}
  \renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
  \renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
  \renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\rm\zihao{-4}}
  \setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{-2pt}
  \listoffigures
}

% ����Ŀ¼
\newcommand\ZJUListofTables{%
  \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\fangsong\zihao{-4}}
  \renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
  \renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
  \renewcommand{\cfttabpagefont}{\rm\zihao{-4}}
  \setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{-2pt}
  \listoftables
}

% ��д�������嵥��������
\newenvironment{ListofSymbol}
{\Nchapter{\ZJU@label@symbol}}
{}

% �ο����ײ���
\DeclareRobustCommand\citenum
   {\begingroup
     \NAT@swatrue\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@parfalse\let\textsuperscript\relax
     \NAT@citexnum[][]}

\newcommand\ZJUthesisbib[1]{%
  \setcitestyle{numbers, round, comma, aysep={}, yysep={,}, notesep={,}}
  \setlength{\bibsep}{0.5ex}
  \setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
  \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\fangsong\zihao{5}}


  \bibliographystyle{ZJUthesis}
  \bibliography{#1}
}

\makeindex

% ����
\newcommand\ZJUindex{%
  \cleardoublepage
  % ������һ����������������ǩλ�ô���
  \phantomsection
  \printindex
}

% ���߼���
\newenvironment{resume}
  {\Nchapter{\ZJU@label@resume}}
  {}

% ��������Ŀ¼
\newenvironment{publications}
  {\Nchapter{\ZJU@label@publications}}
  {}



% 2006����ģ����δʹ�õ�������
\newenvironment{resumesection}[1]
  {{\noindent\normalfont\bfseries #1}
   \list{}{\labelwidth\z@
           \leftmargin 2\ccwd}
   \item\relax}
  {\endlist}
\newenvironment{resumelist}[1]
  {{\noindent\normalfont\bfseries #1}
   \list{}{\labelwidth\z@
           \leftmargin 4\ccwd
           \itemindent -2\ccwd
           \listparindent\itemindent}
   \item\relax}
  {\endlist}

\def\reflect#1{{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\rlap{\kern0.5\wd0
  \special{x:gsave}\special{x:scale -1 1}}\box0 \special{x:grestore}}}
\def\XeTeX{\leavevmode
  \setbox0=\hbox{X\lower.5ex\hbox{\kern-.15em\reflect{E}}\kern-.1667em \TeX}%
  \dp0=0pt\ht0=0pt\box0 }

% ������ʾ��4������ chapter section subsection subsubsection�����ʵ���С
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newtheoremstyle{break}% name
  {}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%      Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `ZJUthesis.cls'.
```

Please give me suggestion to run the code successfully.

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example, aka MWE, that reproduces the error?

Comment: The issue is with the class file. It uses CJK package for including Chinese in the document. At the \makecovepage, gives error:

Package CJK Error: Invalid character code.

Comment: Well, nowadays the most popular way to use Chinese characters in LaTeX is to use [CTeX kit](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit) which invokes different packages depending on the compiling engines.

Comment: How can i use CTex kit? How can i install specific package? Previously, i have installed CTeX_2.9.2.164 and used it. I can even make documents on latex with WinEdt 10.2 but problem comes when i use it for my thesis because it uses Chinese Characters to make cover pages etc.

Comment: Something bad happened after installing Tex Live.

Comment: (Main.out) (Main.out)
Missing character: There is no · in font ptmr7t!

! Package CJK Error: Invalid character code.

See the CJK package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.120 \makeCoverPage
                    
? 

Process has been terminated ...

Comment: Welcome @SyedAmeerAhmedGillani // What the other comments try to convey: We simply can't help you if we can't see and try your code. None of us has a crytal ball, unfortunately. And Latex is powerful, which is a different way to state "it's complex, too". // So, this question will probably be closed for that reason "missing code". Once you can provide it, we'll be happy to help you along.

Comment: @MS-SPO My tex file is UTF-8 encoded. I have tried Miktex with various version. Problem still appears. Changed ctexbook with ctexart. Other issues arise.

Comment: @putianyi888 detailed code is attached for your reference.

Comment: Your template is too old. Why not use the [latest version](https://github.com/TheNetAdmin/zjuthesis) on github?

Comment: @Stephen I could run my latex files with old template before installing Tex Live. Some how Tex Live did not install and damaged some files on my system. Now, the same code does not run in WinEdt 10.2 with MikTex 2.9. I only seek help to find the issue which damaged my system after installing Tex Live.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the MikTeX?@SyedAmeerAhmedGillani

Comment: Your template file doesn't seem to be in UTF-8 as the characters don't show up here. Can you convert that to UTF8 and update your question?

Comment: @ Stephen.  I have reinstalled Miktex many times. It does not solve issue. Same template was working before.  There seems a package issue which is giving error.  After installing Tex Live, this problem occured.  What could be the possible reason? Need experts opinion. 

@

Comment: @Pitianyi888. I am using UTF-8 in document settings. I am also adding UTF-8 package in tex file. What else i should do for conversion?  Please guide.

Comment: Your shown code depends on `\input` of several files we do not have. Therefore we cannot test the code. Please try to show a real [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided an MWE, I'm gonna give my solution for Chinese documents for your reference.

I use `\documentclass{ctexbook}` that is basically Chinese `\documentclass{book}`. You could switch to `ctexart` for article, etc. There is no need for explicitly including CJK.

ctex classes force you to compile in XeLaTeX. The tex files should be encoded in UTF-8.

I use TeXLive. For whatever reason, if you can't install it, then you have a few alternatives.

- Use online services such as Overleaf, or its Chinese counterpart, TeXPage. Note that they have a runtime limit which, if you have a lot of figures in your thesis, could be exceeded, in which case you need to pay for a premium. GitHub workflow has a much longer time cap for a single compilation. It does have a 2000 minute cap for a month but that should be long enough.
- Uninstall and re-install MikTeX.

Comment: My tex file is UTF-8 encoded. I have tried Miktex with various version. Problem still appears. Changed ctexbook with ctexart. Other issues arise.